# Transform php shortcode into a widget

Tags: widgets, shortcode

I have this bit of php that calls a short code with the date of today in the format i need.

`<?php $today = date('d.m');`

`echo do_shortcode('[table id=1 column_widths="10%|10%|80%" filter="'.$today.'" /]'); ?>`

I can put it in a page template and that works, but I would like to use it in a html/txt widget. How can I make a widget from the above?

Comment: You are asking for a [shortcode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API), but I think you are actually looking for a [widget](http://codex.wordpress.org/Widget_API).

Answer (score 0):

You can enable shortcodes in text widgets with following code:-

```
<?php
// This code enables Shortcodes in WordPress Text Widget
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
?>
```